# How do I set the OutputDirectory for msbuild pack?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

Previously using 'nuget', one could run 'nuget pack -OutputDirectory ../../output' for example. How can I do this with msbuild pack? I am using VS2017.

Comment: Have you tried using /p:PackageOutputPath ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dotnet pack` has an option to set the output path:

```
$ dotnet pack -h
  ...
    -o, --output <OUTPUT_DIR>             Directory in which to place built packages.
```

So you can do `dotnet pack -o ../artifacts/packages`

Answer (score 42):

Just to confirm what is mentioned in the comments: you can specify `/p:PackageOutputPath="c:\output"` in which case the .nupkg files will be created in the "c:\output" directory.

Comment: Where is the documentation of this msbuild's arguments?
I didn't manage to find that even on msbuild.exe /help command.

Comment: @MostafaArmandi the documentation is here (at least for now):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target